# 2 view controllers, each has its own xib, one of them is a subclass of another?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, inheritance, uiviewcontroller

I have a custom class inherited from `UIViewController`. Let I call it "VC1". I need to subclass it (create "VC2" with its own xib). Then I try to create and use VC2. The problem is VC2 used but with xib from VC1.

How to solve this issue? May it happen because of VC1 is written in Obj-C and VC2 in Swift?

Initialization code:

```
let vc = ViewController2(nibName: "ViewController2", bundle: nil)
```

Comment: You need to override the code of VC1 which choose the nib.

Comment: tried to override, tried to create a file and specify a concrete xib file - doesn't work while VC2 is subclassing VC1

Comment: can you please show how you attach nib in your VC1?

Comment: it is a simple view - nothing special which has influence on this behaviour

Comment: Do you explicitly tell VC1 to pick a nib in your code?

Comment: Again - I tried 2 ways: 1)override `nibName` method; 2)via constructor with specifying a concrete nib name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146838/discussion-between-vyachaslav-gerchicov-and-shamas-s).

Comment: Please post the code you use to initialize the view controllers. We need to see how you initialize those first...

Comment: added. `ViewController1` is not created. Both view controllers don't have overriden constructors

Answer (score 0):

This way should usually work. But my case is special:

First view controller contains code:

```
NSArray* items = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ViewController1" owner:self options:nil];
IRSubscriptionInfoView* pageContentView = [items objectAtIndex:1];
```

So in the code for vc2 I still try to get some info from nib for vc1.

could be fixed by replacing `@"ViewController1"` -> `[self nibName]` and adding a check for `items.count`

This is the answer to my own question

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16441375)

Comment: It is the answer for my question. What is the problem?

Comment: If this is the answer to your question then please accept it as the answer to your question. From the text of your answer it is not clear that this is really the answer but more of a question: "This way should _usually_  work. But my case is special".

Comment: I can't - "You can accept your own answer in 2 days"

Comment: Fair enough. But please make sure that it is immediately clear that this is the answer. Write something like: "This is the answer to my own question". I was not able to see that this is a answer. It looked more like a comment or additional information to your original question.